# <br/> tags is automatically getting added to html tags in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, html-editor

Whenever I'm adding HTML contents via CKEditor it automatically appends a "br" tag at the end of each other html tags.

How can I remove it?

```
CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
CKEDITOR.config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
CKEDITOR.replace(elemId,
{
    resize_enabled: false,
    entities: false,
    basicEntities: false,
    entities_greek: false,
    entities_latin: false,
}
```

Comment: Try to show us some code on how you are adding HTML to editor?

Comment: And how you're getting it back?

Comment: @Mohan : Thanks for replying.I've added the piece of code.

Comment: @Reinmar : I'm adding a <ul><li></li></ul> via CKeditor. Output is like this when I view the source from the editor... <ul><br/><li><br/></li><br/></ul><br/>

Comment: 5154 was closed as invalid, because author was replacing `\r\n` with `<br>` on his server. If you do the same, then just stop. If not you have to show the working sample proving existence of this issue, because it WFM.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't remove them!**

They are there because the `contenteditable` implementation in Firefox (and I think other non-ie browsers needs them to be there in order to render the elements properly, and allow the caret to be placed in them.

CKeditor's export functions should automatically remove them from the markup, you I wouldn't worry about them unless they are causing a specific problem while you are editing.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting the html in the form of a string you can just run .replace('',''). if you are consernd about the br tags that you want to keep, then just replace them with a random symbol that is never used before you parse the string.